# The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries

Tags: android, dependencies, jakarta-mail

I am making an email application which is giving the error in this question's title. How can I fix this problem? I am giving my codes screenshot if it is helps to find solution.

[image]

Comment: WindRider's answer is the correct and official one. You should change your acceptance so that future users can find that answer.

Comment: please consider the accepted answer, as the currently accepted answer is not a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems to be something they intentionally broke in ADT r17.  See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c6.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I solved this problem with add another jar to the app, because I was already upgrade the eclipse ADT to r17. But the fact that the reason of this problem is r17. Thanks again

Comment: Note also that this is planned to be fixed in ADT r20 (in preview 2, not yet released as of the time I'm writing this).  See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c21.

Comment: please see the answer provided by WindRider - it provides details about the fix I alluded to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 36):

There is an official solution to this:

> Allow src/doc attachement for 3rd party jars in libs/
>
> Since those jars are added dynamically through a classpath container,
>   the devs cannot set the source path and the javadoc through Eclipse UI
>   (container don't allow editing those). To fix this, and to make sure
>   that both paths are picked up not only by the current project, but
>   also by other projects (if the current project is a library project),
>   the value is set by a file sitting next to the jar file. The file is
>   name after the jar file, adding .properties at the end. For instance
>   foo.jar -> foo.jar.properties It can currently contain 2 properties:
>   src: relative or absolute path to the source folder (or archive). doc:
>   relative or absolute path to the javadoc.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/35702/

EDIT: [Explanation in Google I/O 2012 video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Erd2k6EKxCQ#t=2918s)

**Example, for Joda-Time 2.1:**

```
cd $PROJECT/libs
touch joda-time-2.1.jar.properties
```

And insert the following, making sure the path is correct:

```
src=/Users/josh.oneal/SDKs/joda-time-2.1/joda-time-2.1-sources.jar
doc=/Users/josh.oneal/SDKs/joda-time-2.1/joda-time-2.1-javadoc.jar
```

You can now right click your project in Eclipse and refresh, then Command / Ctrl + Click a class such as `DateTime` to view its source.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is absolutely the correct answer to the issue. I've edited your post to include an example for future viewers.

Comment: what if the jar is added through another android project in the workspace (settings > android > add library project)?

Comment: Thanks! NB. I also needed to restart Eclipse for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! It seems you need actually both src and doc. I tried adding only src and it didn't work until I've added doc.

Comment: I did not need to do what gunar describes (in Eclipse Juno) so this has either been fixed or guno's problem was caused by something else.

Comment: See [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c21) : `src: relative or absolute path to the source folder (or archive). doc: relative or absolute path to the javadoc.` The properties file is a standard Java properties file, using ISO 8859-1 character encoding.

Comment: I also need src and doc folder. When I use only doc folder, the souce's annotation can NOT display? Is there any way only use the doc folder?

Comment: Whatever I do, this does not work for me. Is the javadoc listed in the Configure Build Path dialogue when you do it?

Answer (score 10):

When you use eclipse, you can fix it by selecting your library project and go to Properties > Order and Export and move your src dependency above the gen dependency. You can also manually edit your .classpath file to do the same. Source attachments should work after you clean this project. Credits for figuring out the solution goes to [NightCrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942340/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe/19050848#19050848)

Comment: This worked for me! What I did was: right click on the project that is a library to my main project. Select `properties` -> `java build path` -> `order and export` -> move the `[projectname]/src` line all the way to the top !!

Comment: This worked for me too. Basically, I moved the [projectname]/src to above [projectname]/.apt_generated; the latter was being picked for the source in the app's project

Comment: I tried virtually all other accepted answers, with no results. This worked for me once I realized it needed to be done in the LIBRARY. I kept doing it to the host project and that did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the workaround in comment 8

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c8.
"Hello, I have solution to problem described in a comment 3:

1. Move content from libs folder back to lib because ADT 17 automatically add all jars from libs directory under Android dependencies.
2. Add dependencies from your lib directory as normal eclipse dependency (the old way before ADT 17). Link JAR files with their source JAR files or Javadoc.
3. In Project properties -> Java build path -> Order and export check all your added dependencies to be included with project class files.
4. Select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties"

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem while using javax.mail to access gmail. According to this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546926/could-not-find-class-error-when-trying-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-the-gd), there seems to be some sort of problem with it and Android.

I solved it by using this JAR files, here : http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the real and most simple solution to this.

THIS IS USING THE IDE, AND WILL ALWAYS WORK. THE SIMPLIEST SOLUTION.

If you have a complex structure where one library project use a library, and that library project is used for your project, and so on. Or in any case... do this to solve this problem:

Import to eclipse the library you want to be able to see the source code for debugging proccess.

Mark the Is Library Option by Right Clicking the project > Propertie > Android

Then go to all the library projects that uses that library, 
and Right Click the project > Propertie > Android > Add > and select your library.

Then, go to your project and the library project that is in the Project>Properties>Android>Library_name, click remove and add it again, in order to be able to assume the changes in the library project.

And that's all. It's just use the project of the library itself instead of just using the jar of the library you want to see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one solution: go to project folder and open `.classpath` file.
Here re-order `classpathentry` in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
```

First is `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>` and second - `<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>`. In my case it resolves all problems.