# how to resolve eclipse error Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting "source not found" error in debug and run mode of eclipse (java). I have tried each and every solution but its not working.

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

waiting for any kind of solution. thanks in advance :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942340/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe/19050848#19050848 This work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a native method, there is no source available.

For Java code you can download sources usually, but for native code you can't really find it (well, you could use the openjdk source, but it's not Java code anymore, it's C or C++).

Comment: @AdnanMushtaq Download the src of jar of that and aad to your project. Can you please tell which jar it is ?

Comment: @suresh Atta, didnt get you

Answer (score 0):

you can not add source for native methods. if you want to add source of your java code
click on

> edit source lookup path -> java project -> your project

or

> right click on your project -> build path -> configure build path ->
>   source -> here you can add your project folders as source

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the project. Eclipse does not automatically pick up folders (or files) dropped into it's project directory.