# The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Private Libraries' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jsoup

I added jsoup library to /lib folder in my project.

When debugging, I'm getting the following error:

```
The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Private Libraries' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries
```

Here is my code snippet which the error is pointing to:

```
              Document htmlFile = null;
                try {

                    htmlFile = Jsoup.connect("www.someURL.com").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What is causing the error and how to solve it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow source modifications to source attachments on its entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942340/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe)

Comment: But, the container is different here ('Android Private Libraries') and context of the question is  different as well.