# Scoreloop, Terms Of Service

Tags: java, android

I have a question by implementing scoreloop on android. The official tutorial gives this code to make sure, that the user has accepted:

```
ScoreloopManagerSingleton.get().askUserToAcceptTermsOfService(this, new Continuation<Boolean>() {
    public void withValue(final Boolean value, final Exception error) {
        if (value != null && value) {
            // user did accept the TOS, you can continue interacting with Scoreloop
        }
    }
 });
```

The sad problem: When I am using this, I have to import the "Continuation". Eclipse want this:

```
import com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Continuation;
```

But when I want to know the Declaration: Source not found: The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Android Private Libraries' which does not allow modifications to source attachements on its entries.
The App does not work.

Comment: Hello again :) check this link out, it seems to the problem you are having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075453/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe

Comment: Thanks. I guess he is right. But I do not understand how I can fix my problem. :(

Comment: Check the very bottom answer by Stefan, that should be what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: I tried it, this is not working. :(

Comment: "what if the jar is added through another android project in the workspace (settings > android > add library project)? –  ferdy182 Nov 16 '12 at 14:48" - Why no one answered? I did this.

Comment: Then the library will be in your project list in eclipse and you can "right click on the project that is the library. Select properties -> java build path -> order and export -> move the [projectname]/src line all the way to the top"

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is not working. :/

Comment: After restarting, I get a new error: The JAR file C:\...\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar has no source attachment.

Comment: Ok. Now I am back too my first problem...